# Django blog app that uses pygments and works like StackOverflow

Tags: python, django, pygments, zinnia

I'd like to put together a Django Blog App that uses [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) for **code markup** within the Blog.  I'd like to be able to mark up the main text similar to StackOverflow with `*`, `_` or <kbd>cmd+K</kbd> for special notation within the code to add `href` or **bold** etc.

Is there a Django App that can do this?  Looked at [zinnia](http://docs.django-blog-zinnia.com/en/v0.14/index.html) but it seems pretty robust, and not sure how to extend it to use **Pygments**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [django-pygments](http://od-eon.com/labs/django-pygments/) is a Django app (Django-Pygments integration) that provides a template tag and 2 filters for doing syntax highlighting with Pygments.